# Strange variable name after subsetting dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe `df` in Rstudio. I want to extract the column `diff` and removing the first row with the following code:

```
# Import data and packages
library(outbreaks)
df <- measles_hagelloch_1861[order(measles_hagelloch_1861$date_of_prodrome), c(1, 3)]
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)

# Generate variable diff
df$diff <- difftime(lag(df$date_of_prodrome, 1), df$date_of_prodrome, units = "days" )

# Subset dataset
time_between_two_events <- as.data.frame(df[-1, 'diff'])
head(time_between_two_events)
```

and result

```
  df[-1, "diff"]
1              2
2              6
3              0
4              1
5              3
6              0
```

Could you please explain why I get the strange variable name as `df[-1, "diff"]`? I expect that it should be `diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the subset has only one column it changes the dataframe to a vector.

```
df[-1, 'diff']
#Time differences in days
#[1]  -2  -6   0  -1  -3   0  -1  -1 .....
```

this vector is then converted to data.frame giving a weird name.

Use `drop = FALSE` to avoid coercing dataframe to vector.

```
df[-1, 'diff', drop = FALSE]

#       diff
#173  -2 days
#177  -6 days
#178   0 days
#174  -1 days
#45   -3 days
#183   0 days
#175  -1 days
#...
#...
```